# Can't connect iPhone as an audio input to my Mac

Tags: ios

I've been trying to get my iPhone audio to channel through my Mac, and what I read was that if I plug my iPhone into my Mac, I can open Audio MIDI setup and click "Enable" under the iPhone, and then it will be as I want it.
[image: Enable]
However, if I click enable, the word "iPhone" and a USB icon appear in the menu, with everything greyed out. [image: Greyed out audio menu]
If I click the [name]'s iPhone with the iPhone next to it, It just says 
" Press the Enable button to place your iOS device in Inter-device Audio and MIDI Mode. In this mode, your iPhone or iPad will appear as an audio input device on your Mac, enabling the recording of non-telephony audio via the Lightning to USB cable. This setting also permits sending and receiving MIDI messages through the Lightning to USB cable using your favourite music applications"
[image]
There is no issue with USB lockdown or anything, because I can go into iTunes and sync my music, Podcasts, etc.
I have tried playing music through the Apple Music app to check, but it plays through the iPhone speakers.
Anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: It enables the iPhone as an input source in apps like FaceTime etc, pick it as your input in there; it's already enabled & ready to go in audio/midi. Play something from iTunes to test. It doesn't feed the mic afaik, only 'non-telephony' audio.

Comment: I did, but it played through the iPhone speakers.

Comment: Reboot both, try again.

Comment: On my Catalina, the device first shows `Enable`, then after I press it once, it quickly resets itself. And in between I can see a new iPhone device appear among the Input device list for only a second and then disappears. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You just overlooked ther fact that by the time your iPhone button says "Disable", 
it is already connected!

Go to your Digital Audio Workstation (DAW)/Preferences/Audio and point to your iPhone as an Input Device.

In Ableton:

[image]

and in Logic Pro X for example:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: On my Catalina, the device first shows Enable, then after I press it once, it quickly resets itself. And in between I can see a new iPhone device appear among the Input device list for only a second and then disappears. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Didyou try to exchange the cable for a new one kakyo ??